# DIV content moves Need to stay aligned right

Tags: css, html, positioning, alignment

Having a tough time trying get this navigation bar to stay in the same place aligned right as the numbers change.

Please keep in mind I know little to nothing about div and how to do this, other than trial an error. I appreciate your professional advice.

The one on the left works great, but the one on the right moves as double digit numbers begin to appear (in the navigation) when navigating to those pages.

I simply need to keep the top NEXT >> always aligned to the right regardless of the hidden content to the left.

This is apparent as the pages are navigated.

[Next>> Navigation in center right](http://www.forestwander.com/flowers/page/37/)

This is what the div currently looks like.

```
<td width='33%' align="right" valign="top">
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 135px; position: absolute;">
<div style="float:left;width:640px;margin:50px 0px 0px -475px;">
<?php mySideBar(22); ?>
</div>
```

Below is for the numbers below Next >>

```
<div style="float:left;width:500px;margin:25px 0px 0px -241px;">
<?php mySideBar(22); ?>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: You have 359 HTML errors, 24 CSS errors, use antiquated/deprecated properties and have a disease we call 'divitis'. You won't get much help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `float:right;` instead of `float:left;`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I did try this and it has not worked thus far. Thank you